# Swipeleft/swiperight not working

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, touch, pug, swipe

I'm making a presentation for the iPad. I want to use the swipeleft and swiperight from the jquery-mobile library.

At the moment I'm testing everything in google chrome. I did enable 'Emulate touch screen'

My problem: I don't get a message in the console, so the swipe doesn't work.

The versions I'm using:

**jquery**: jquery-**2.1.1**.js and **jquery-mobile**: jquery.mobile-**1.4.5**.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Previous/next slide on swipe
   $('.bg, header').on('swipeleft', function(e){
      console.log("swipe left");
   });
   $('.bg, header').on('swiperight', function(e){
      console.log("swipe right");
   });
});
```

My jade code:

```
header
    h1
      | Title

  .body
    img(src="#{baseUrl}img/bodybg.jpg", alt="body").bg
```

If I do the following (bind and touchend), I get 'swipe left/swipe right' in the console:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Previous/next slide on touchend
   $('.bg, header').bind('touchend', function(e){
      console.log("touchend");
   });
   $('.bg, header').bind('touchend', function(e){
      console.log("touchend");
   });
});
```

But I don't want to use touchend, I want to use swiperight and swipeleft! What am I missing here?N

Comment: Please post your html markup. Your code should work, but use pagecontainer events to attach listeners rather than using ready.

Comment: Replace `ready` with [`pagecreate`](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/).

Comment: $(document).pagecreate(function() { gave me Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: `$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {`

Comment: errors are gone, but still no text in the console, very strange

Comment: ok, try `$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e) { $(".bg, header", e.target).on("swipe", function () { console.log("swipe"); }); });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67544/discussion-between-omar-and-gilko).

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$('.bg, header').on('swipeleft', function(e){
  console.log("swipe left");
});

$('.bg, header').on('swiperight', function(e){
  console.log("swipe right");
});
```

to:

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '.bg, header',function(e){
  console.log("swipe left");
});

$(document).on('swiperight', '.bg, header',function(e){
  console.log("swipe right");
});
```

This way you are delegating swipe event, it doesn't matter if '.bg, header' are loaded into the DOM or not.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qtfathho/