# jquery mobile swipe event wont fire on cordova

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I recently created this test: http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/4548/ for swiping some divs. The test work fine but if I try it on my phone or in ripple(phone simulation in chrome) the swipe events wont fire at all.

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <title>WeightTracker</title>
        <!-- WeightTracker references -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/frameworks/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/database.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/frameworks/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart', 'timeline']}]}"></script>
        <script src="scripts/frameworks/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="div1" class="cardcontainer previouscard">
                <div id="chartcard" class="card medium col s12 active">
                    <div id="chartselectwrapper">
                        <select id="chartselect">
                            <option value="7" selected>1 Week</option>
                            <option value="30">1 Months</option>
                            <option value="60">2 Months</option>
                            <option value="180">6 Months</option>
                            <option value="365">1 Year</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="chart_div"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="div2" class="cardcontainer activecard">
                <div id="textcard" class="card col s12 previous">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <table id="tabledata">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th data-field="date">Date</th>
                                    <th data-field="weight">Weight</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="div3" class="cardcontainer nextcard">
                <div id="settingscard" class="card col s12 next">
                    <div class="card-content input-field">
                        <select id="units">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Units</option>
                            <option value="kg">Metric(kg)</option>
                            <option value="lbs">Imperial(lbs)</option>
                        </select>
                        <label id="unitsettlabel">unit</label>
                        <a id="savesettings" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="mdi-content-save right"></i>Save</a><br>
                        <a id="deleteall" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="mdi-alert-warning right"></i>Delete all data</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs" class="col s12">
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li id="charts" class="tab col s4"><a href="#test2">Charts</a></li>
                    <li id="text" class="tab col s4"><a class="active" href="#test1">Recent</a></li>
                    <li id="settings" class="tab col s4"><a href="#test3">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );


    $("#div1").on("swipeleft", function () {
        $("#div1").removeClass("activecard");
        $("#div2").removeClass("nextcard");
        $("#div3").removeClass("nextcard");
        $("#div1").addClass("previouscard");
        $("#div2").addClass("activecard");
        $("#div3").addClass("nextcard");

    });
    $("#div1").on("swiperight", function () { });

    $("#div2").on("swiperight", function () {
        $("#div2").removeClass("activecard");
        $("#div3").removeClass("nextcard");
        $("#div1").removeClass("previouscard");
        $("#div1").addClass("activecard");
        $("#div2").addClass("nextcard");
        $("#div3").addClass("nextcard");
    });
    $("#div2").on("swipeleft", function () {
        $("#div2").removeClass("activecard");
        $("#div3").removeClass("nextcard");
        $("#div1").removeClass("previouscard");
        $("#div3").addClass("activecard");
        $("#div2").addClass("previouscard");

    });

    $("#div3").on("swiperight", function () {
        $("#div3").removeClass("activecard");
        $("#div2").removeClass("previouscard");
        $("#div2").addClass("activecard");
        $("#div1").addClass("previouscard");
        $("#div3").addClass("nextcard");

    });
    $("#div3").on("swipeleft", function () { });


    });
```

I tried about everything google and stackoverflow came up with... Anyone got an idea?

I already tried:
[Adding jquery mobile swipe event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293220/adding-jquery-mobile-swipe-event)

[Swipeleft/swiperight not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619467/swipeleft-swiperight-not-working)

and a few more...